# Form validation for Twilio in Django to send a SMS message

Tags: django, twilio

I'm trying to set up Twilio integration inside a DetailView Django page. They look at the detailed view page and can request a booking via from POST method. Upon booking, I would like to send SMS to the owner of the booking, in my case the teacher.

**forms.py**

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
class BookingForm(forms.Form):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    Phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15,validators=[phone_regex],label='Phone')
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self,request,**kwargs):
    form = BookingForm(self.request.POST)
    account_sid = "xxx"
    auth_token = "xxx"
    teacher = Teacher.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    user_phone = form['Phone'].value
    #user_phone = self.request.POST['Phone']
    client.messages.create(
        to=teacher.phone_number,
        from_="+442033225719",
        body="You have a new student" +
             " Student phone number:{}".format(user_phone))
```

And I have a template form, which has 1 input - phone number.

However, when I submit the form, I get the following text message:

Student Phone number: `<bound method BoundField.value of <django.forms.boundfield.Boundfield object at 0x104e5f0b8>>`

Note that if I don't use forms, but instead have a simple user_phone = self.request.POST['Phone'] instead of validating the form using if form.is_valid(), everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need validate form and then get value from cleaned_data

```
form = BookingForm(self.request.POST)
form.is_valid()
user_phone = form.cleaned_data['Phone']
```